# I have an error code in my getBody() function and I dont know why

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I'm creating this code where the template is selected through a series of If statements.  so it is a changing variable.  I am simply trying to now replace text in the selected template and I keep getting the same error that getBody() is not a function.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
var copy = doc.makeCopy();
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mGCx4yXX_NnLHsHsGWBGkzwAVhG-cTrc');
destination.addFile(copy);
copy.setName(regno + ' statistical analysis');
var copiedTemplateId = copy.getId();

var body = doc.getBody(); 
var header = doc.getHeader();
```

Comment: What is the type for `doc`?  Where is the `getBody` method defined?  Basically, can you clarify why specifically you *expect* `getBody()` to be a function here?

Comment: The getBody() is intended to be used to replace text in the template in subsequent code after this.   the doc and getBody types i guess would be visible in the code somehow... I'm really trying to learn from scratch, so I'm not fully understanding exactly what you are asking.  this is the first time that they are mentioned in the code up until this point.

Comment: Well, the point of what I'm asking is why you expect that function to exist and what you expect it to do?  What documentation or example are you referencing?  What documentation have you looked up?

Comment: I would like that function to be able to allow me to retrieve set text within the template and replace them with data from a spreadsheet for automatic report generation.  the document is a google doc template.

Comment: Try this instead  `var doc = DocumentApp.getById(templateId)`;

Comment: this does not work either.... I really dont know what is going on.  :(

Answer (score 0):

DriveApp.getFileById returns a File.
So, doc is of type File.
There is no "getBody" function for a File, at least it doesn't exist in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file

Comment: is there a way of making a file a document?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this instead: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyidid
Search "DocumentApp.openById", that returns a Document, and then you can use getBody() on that document. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function myfunk() {
  const regno = "test";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("fileid");
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  let name = regno + ' statistical analysis';
  var copy = file.makeCopy(name, destination);
  var copiedTemplateId = copy.getId();
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById(copiedTemplateId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var header = doc.getHeader();
  Logger.log('id: %s, body: %s, header: %s',copiedTemplateId,body,header);
}
```

File was a Google Document and a copied was created in the appropriate directory and renamed correctly.